# Mobile upload refreshes page and file does not upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, smarty

I've asked this question to the admins of Smartjobboard software yet they are so inactive ill ask here...

On mobile phones/Ipads a jobseeker is able to apply to a job with a CV by uploading it and submitting it. However for some reason when a user uploads a CV it will **sometimes** refresh the page and the CV will not be uploaded..However on **desktop** the upload never breaks and works flawlessly

I'm pretty sure its something to do with the page speed or/and how the page loads. But to be proactive in getting this fixed and working as it should I thought id ask you genius people for help :)

Anyway the codes... (Posted in pastebin)

Apply_now.php - http://pastebin.com/JasSWTEg

**The form for applying :**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="applyForm" action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/apply-now/">
    <input type="hidden" name="is_data_submitted" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="listing_id" value="{$listing_id}">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="inputName" style="width:19%">
            [[Attach your CV]]:
        </div>
        <div class="inputField" style="margin-top:7px;">
            <input type="file" name="file_tmp" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input  class="button-green" type="submit" value="[[Apply Now]]" onclick="return applySubmit();"/>
</form>
```

**Apply Script :**

```
function applySubmit() {
    $("#ApplicationForm").hide();
    $("#applyForm").ajaxSubmit(
    {
        url: $("#applyForm").attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) 
        {
            $("#messageBox").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I'm unsure if there is a problem within the applying script/php/code it self. I'm working on the pagespeeds now to eliminate render blocking etc etc to see if its causing the issue.

Comment: The `form` doesnt have a `action` tag. Could that be the cause? The `return false` in your js function says `stop whatever you're doing (eg refresh the page to submit this form`

Comment: That actually has seem to fixed it I added "action="POST"" to the form and my mobile isnt refreshing on upload. However it does "sometimes work not always but sometimes so I'm gonna try on a few different phones and see if it does it again.

Amazing how something so simple can mess it all up. Thanks! And ill let you know!

Comment: Adding the action POST made the upload work fine however when looking inside the account areas and checking my email i didnt actually receive the application - Just added 
action="{$GLOBALS.site_url}/apply-now/" and it worked as it should. Thanks alot :)

Comment: The `action` attribute carries the url. you are mixing it up with the `method` attribute. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.1

Comment: Update - Added the action tag as suggested as it seemd to have worked, Just tried again and it seems to be doing it again. 

Updated the OP to display the new form. Any more insight into this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, add a `action` tag to your html `form`.